# how to assign value to radio button from <s:property> in struts 2

Tags: radio-button, struts

Please tell me how we can assign a value to radio button from property tag in struts 2.

I'm using this code -

```
<s:radio name="id" list="{<s:property value='"client_id"'/>}" ></s:radio>
```

I'm getting this exception -

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /user.jsp(165,68) equal symbol expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to use property tag inside another struts 2 tag. directly use the value like this

```
<s:radio name="id" list="%{client_id}" ></s:radio>
```

but note that **client_id should be a collection**

Comment: did you try {%{"client_id"}}